# Random `invalid argument` in copy function

Tags: php, wordpress, windows-server-2012

I am having trouble updating Wordpress from the admin area. The update process crashes in pure random fashion. It says that file copy failed. I've added the lines to log source and destination paths, but it's not getting clear:

> [21-Nov-2014 07:23:50 UTC] Source: D:/WEBROOT/domain.com/www/wp-content/upgrade/wordpress-4.tmp/wordpress/wp-admin/includes/image.php
>
> [21-Nov-2014 07:23:50 UTC] Dest: D:/WEBROOT/domain.com/www/wp-admin/includes/image.php
>
> [21-Nov-2014 07:23:50 UTC] PHP Warning:  copy(D:/WEBROOT/domain.com/www/wp-admin/includes/image.php): failed to open stream: Invalid argument in D:\WEBROOT\domain.com\www\wp-admin\includes\class-wp-filesystem-direct.php on line 219

... And suddenly, a few tries later ...

> [21-Nov-2014 07:26:41 UTC] Source: D:/WEBROOT/domain.com/www/wp-content/upgrade/wordpress-4.tmp/wordpress/wp-admin/includes/image.php
>
> [21-Nov-2014 07:26:41 UTC] Dest: D:/WEBROOT/domain.com/www/wp-admin/includes/image.php
>
> No error, upgrade succeeded

That's a little confusing. The Web server user has been granted full control privileges prior to upgrade.

The OS is Windows Server 2012, the old Wordpress version is 4.0, the new version is 4.0.1. PHP version is 5.5

Comment: But has Wordpress updated? I noticed that happened to me too, in my case giving timeout in the process. The best way is to download the latest version, backup and replace files on server.

Comment: It did upgrade after a few tries. "The best way" is boring, I like one button stuff :)

Comment: I understand you like one button stuff but that doesn't mean it's the best way to do it. I suspect the cause of the issue is related with the fact the update was recently released with a lot of people wanting to access it meaning that our local Wordpress installations are not able to correctly fetch the file. Today I updated a few more sites with no problem.